# How to generate negative audio waves from input sound in javascript?

Tags: javascript, audio, microphone, getusermedia

I found a javascript that captures the current microphone input just to send it out again. You can see it here:

https://codepen.io/MyXoToD/pen/bdb1b834b15aaa4b4fcc8c7b50c23a6f?editors=1010 (only works with https).

I was wondering how I can generate the "negative" waves of the sound captured. Just like "noise cancellation" works. So the script detects the current noise around me and whenever there is a wave going up I want to generate a wave that is going down to cancel each other out. Is there a way to do this in javascript?

So this outputs the current sound recored:

```
var input = audio_context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
volume = audio_context.createGain();
volume.gain.value = 0.8;
input.connect(volume);
volume.connect(audio_context.destination);
```

The question is how to produce the negative of this sound and output this instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already streaming your signal through a Web Audio chain. What you need to do is chain an [AudioWorklet node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioWorkletNode) between the input and output nodes (after or before the gain node, doesn't matter). The script for the worklet would be a very simple sign inversion.

```js
await audio_context.audioWorklet.addModule("negate.js")
const negateNode = new AudioWorkletNode(audio_context, "negate")
input.connect(negationNode)
negateNode.connect(volume)
```

The worklet ("negate.js") :

```js
class AudioNegator extends AudioWorkletProcessor {
  process([input], [output]) {
    for (let channel = 0; channel < input.length; channel++)
      for (let i = 0; i < 128; i++)
        output[channel][i] = -input[channel][i]
    return false
  }
}
registerProcessor("negate", AudioNegator)
```

Comment: I was quite surprised to have this answer approved now when it was talking about the defunct AudioWorkers. Updated to show something that actually works in 2024.